# How to resize the screen of the virtual android

Tags: android-studio

[image][image]

Is there any way of resizing the screen in correlation with the virtual device? I have been looking everywhere but none seems to have my problem or I may be missing something. Waited for the device to boot and it still has the same problem. When resizing the device the screens get much smaller following resizing.

Comment: Wait until the emulated device has been booted, then you should be able to resize the virtual device and the virtual display. At least it works out of the box without problems.

Comment: @Robert the problem still persists. I've installed it long before and it works fine but now I don't know what could be the problem. I have a missing adb but that doesn't effect the screen size does it?